# Setting default download directory and headless chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a rails app, and am running capybara & selenium, and using chrome for end-to-end testing. I want to set the default download directory while running chrome headless.

Here's how I have it setup in my support/env.rb:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
  'chromeOptions' =>  {
    'args' => %w(headless disable-gpu window-size=1920,1080),
    'prefs' => {
      'download.default_directory' => DownloadHelpers::PATH.to_s
    }
  }
)
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app,
  browser: :chrome,
  #args: ["--window-size=1024,768"], #UNCOMMENT TO HAVE BROWSER WINDOW POP UP
  desired_capabilities: capabilities
end
```

I have noticed that if I leave off

```
'args' => %w(headless disable-gpu window-size=1920,1080)
```

Then the default download directory is set, however, the browser automatically pops up, which I want to disable.

When I have both:

```
    'args' => %w(headless disable-gpu window-size=1920,1080),
'prefs' => {
  'download.default_directory' => DownloadHelpers::PATH.to_s
}
```

It runs headless, but the default download path is not set.

I have the following versions:

capybara   (2.14.2)

selenium-webdriver   (3.6.0)

chromedriver-helper   (1.1.0)

Comment: This is a nice hack to set the download directory for headless chrome. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481#c78

Comment: Beautiful Barney! This seemed to work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Guess what, I happened to go through all those yesterday to implement the same in Javascript. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481#c78 and

Changed my setup to:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1366,768')

  options.add_preference(:download, directory_upgrade: true,
                                prompt_for_download: false,
                                default_directory: 
 '/User/paulo/projects/app/tmp')

  options.add_preference(:browser, set_download_behavior: { behavior: 'allow' })

  driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)

  bridge = driver.browser.send(:bridge)

  path = '/session/:session_id/chromium/send_command'
  path[':session_id'] = bridge.session_id

  bridge.http.call(:post, path, cmd: 'Page.setDownloadBehavior',
                                params: {
                                  behavior: 'allow',
                                  downloadPath: '/User/paulo/projects/app/tmp'
                            })

  driver
end
```

Note you will have to put in your own downloadPath.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this, I tried using user43395's solution, and could not get it to work. However, I finally discovered the issue - in my particular case, the download directory needed to have BACKSLASHES instead of forward slashes. So for example:

```
downloadPath: '/User/paulo/projects/app/tmp'
```

needed to be

```
downloadPath: '\\User\\paulo\\projects\\app\\tmp'
```

Otherwise, everything else in their answer worked like a charm! I wanted to put this here in case anyone else has been struggling with not getting it to work.